# download file and run an sql update query

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have a web app that has my users upload a file. I then have to download that file, and change the status in the database so I can keep track of which files I have downloaded. 
The HTML form is

```
echo '<a href="uploads/'.$filename.'" onClick="DownloadFile($filename)">Download File</a>'
```

And the function:

```
function DownloadFile($filename){
    if (file_exists($filename)){
            header ( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header ( 'Content-Length: ' .filesize($filename));
            header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachement; filename='.basename($filename));
                readfile($filename);
                $query = "UPDATE table SET status = '1' WHERE file_id = '$file_id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
                    if ($result){
                        echo 'updated';
                    }else{
                            echo 'Error updating database';
                    }
            exit();
    }
    }
```

The file downloads fine, but the SQL update statement doesn't change the status, or echo either the outcomes. Any insight would be welcome as this is the first time I have tried working with a download function.

Comment: `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` is still active when you `echo` so you won't see it, btw see if it doesn't append to the files you download, that would be funny. As for `file_id` see _Loïc_'s answer.

Comment: You can't do that like that. You're trying to call php function from onclick, which calls JavaScript functions. You should have a link to a separate file the pushes the download and updates the db. Your php function of never being run. The only reason your file is downloading is because the href points to the file itself

Comment: this and also this lets people edit files from anyone as `$file_id` is easily tamperable.

Comment: @Loic, no not at all.

Comment: Of course. File_id comes from `$_REQUEST` change it and you can set status to any file.

Comment: Wrong. 1- you don't even know where fileid comes from, and 2- that code as it is never gets called

Comment: so if the function is not even being called, how could the DB get updated?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me very well , note that i have added download limit

```
 if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header('Content-type: application/zip'); //this could be a different header 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.zip"');

    ignore_user_abort(true);

    $context = stream_context_create();
    $file = fopen($filename, 'rb', FALSE, $context);
    while(!feof($file))
    {
        echo stream_get_contents($file, 5120);
    }
    fclose($file);

    // SQL HERE if Success

    flush();
    }

    else{

        echo "file is moved or deleted, Please generate download link again.";
    }
```